# LISP - is returning lists full of#

Tags: list, compression, lisp, common-lisp

Does anyone know how to solve the compressing of big lists of Common Lisp

i'm getting (# # # #) (# 0 #) kind of lists instead of ((black round full) (white square empty)...) as it should

Lisp is compressing my lists and I want to send to files without the compression.
How?

Comment: Show your function, input and output.

Comment: input : '(nil(( 
  (0 0 0 0)
  (0 0 0 0)
  (0 0 0 0)
  (0 0 0 0) 
 )
 ((branca redonda alta oca)(preta redonda alta oca)(branca redonda baixa oca)(preta redonda baixa oca)(branca quadrada alta oca)(preta quadrada alta oca)(branca quadrada baixa oca)(preta quadrada baixa oca)(branca redonda alta cheia) (preta redonda alta cheia)
  (branca redonda baixa cheia)
  (preta redonda baixa cheia)
  (branca quadrada alta cheia)
  (preta quadrada alta cheia)
  (branca quadrada baixa cheia)
  (preta quadrada baixa cheia)
 )
) 0 0)))

Comment: output: ((# # # #) (# # # # #)) inside the file
can't send the function because it's like a full project. 
but basically we are creating a game that's generating sucessors and saving them to a file till we get the solution

Comment: It's not about some compression or such, I think there is something about your code. Try to isolate small piece and show us.

Comment: There are no `#` in your list;  the printer is doing some things to *abbreviate* output for human consumption, or to indicate repeated structured.  If you take the first element of one of the lists that's being printed with `#`, you'll see that it still has the elements you expect it to.  In addition to \*print-circle\*, you should look into [\*print-readably\*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pr_rda.htm).

Comment: Please edit your problem statement and add your code there, properly formatted. Do not put your code in via comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant variable for this is [`*print-level*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/v_pr_lev.htm#STprint-levelST).  It is unusual that it is set to such a low value.

Lispworks additionally has `dbg:*debug-print-level*` and `hcl:*trace-print-level*` which it uses for debugging and tracing output, respectively.

In order to print everything, bind `*print-level*` to `nil`.  This can be done either explicitly, as in

```
(let ((*print-level* nil))
  (print my-stuff))
```

or by using the keyword parameter of [`write`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_wr_pr.htm#write):

```
(write my-stuff :level nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `*print-circle*` is set to `T`. Hard to say, given your vague description.

```
CL-USER 7 > (let ((foo '(BRANCA REDONDA BAIXA CHEIA))) (list foo foo))
(#1=(BRANCA REDONDA BAIXA CHEIA) #1#)

CL-USER 8 > (setf *print-circle* nil)
NIL

CL-USER 9 > (let ((foo '(BRANCA REDONDA BAIXA CHEIA))) (list foo foo))
((BRANCA REDONDA BAIXA CHEIA) (BRANCA REDONDA BAIXA CHEIA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, LispWorks starts to get memory full and start to use # to save memory. if I restart the Lispworks (sometimes works, sometimes don't) it will show the full list.

Thanks for the help!